# cocoapods 1.2 Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries inconsistent behavior

Tags: cocoapods-1.2

**What is the basis of this?**

[image]

All my targets use the same pods and has $(inherited)
[image]

- Target1 shows  No - $(inherited)
- Target2 shows Yes - $(inherited)
- Target3 shows  No - $(inherited)
- Target4 shows  No - $(inherited)
- Target5 shows  No - $(inherited)
- Target6 shows Yes - $(inherited)
- Target7 shows Yes - $(inherited)

my podfile:

```
def core_pods
    pod 'MRCountryPicker', :git => 'https://github.com/useeless37/MRCountryPicker.git'
    pod 'TrueTime'
    pod 'PermissionScope'
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
    pod 'Mantle'
    pod 'HockeySDK', '~> 4'
    pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 2'
    pod 'GooglePlaces', '~> 2'
    pod 'Stripe'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
    pod 'RestKit'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.3.4'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'SAMKeychain'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
    pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage'
    pod 'ZLPeoplePickerViewController'
    pod 'KVOController'
    pod 'OHHTTPStubs'
end

target 'target1' do
    core_pods
end
target 'target2' do
    core_pods
end
target 'target3' do
    core_pods
end
target 'target4' do
    core_pods
end
target 'target5' do
    core_pods
end
target 'target6' do
    core_pods
end
target 'target7' do
    core_pods
end
```